# Image appears reddish

Tags: image, javafx-8

I have a similar issue. I am loading photo of a person into StackPane/ImageView from a file. At this time the image looks like original. Upon Save button being clicked, the image is inserted in database BLOB field. In SQL, when you view this, the image appears perfectly normal. On View / Modify options, I retrieve the Blob and convert it to Image and load it in the same Imageview. But now it appears with a reddish Background.

[This is the correct image at the time of loading from file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mEfK.png)

[But this is how it appears when I display it from Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3vfb.png)

Comment: You have a similar issue to what?

Answer (score 0):

I did this to my CSS file and it works.

```
.scrollPane.disabled {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
    -fx-background-color: cornsilk;
}

.scrollPane {
    -fx-opacity: 1.0;
    -fx-background-color: cornsilk;
}
```

This is the order of my nodes.

1. Scroll Pane
2. Stack Pane
3. Image View
4. Image